# Wordpress not logged in locally with correct username and password

Tags: login, password, username

I'm unable to logged in wordpress in locally with correct username and password. When I enter the username and password and click the login button, it displays same log in page with empty password field. It doesn't display the error message also. please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try. One of them you have already tried.

Clear your browser cache (which you have stated you have tried), just make sure you cleared everything, cookies and cache.

Try deactivating all plugins by either logging in via SSH or FTP to your server and rename wp-content/plugins to wp-content/plugins_backup.

Change wp theme, it maybe an issue with your current theme. Try changing to one of the defaults like twentyfifteen.

.htaccess could be causing problems so you can once again SSH or FTP to your server and rename .htaccess to htaccess.backup.

Also check your wp-config.php making sure that your site url is defined properly, eg:

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');